# JSTL tag management on RichFaces 3 re-rendering

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

I read various examples on the web where an ajax call sent through a4j tags of ReachFaces 3 re-renders a jstl tag. In this example:

http://relation.to/Bloggers/UsingDynamicallyCreatedRichFacesTabPanelForSearchResults

an ajax call re-renders a c:foreach inside a rich:tabPanel (look at the code after "*Add the next code just after the panel code:*").

My question is: since the c:forEach tag is evaluated during view creation (like any other jstl tag), the portion of the view pointed by the reRender attribute is reconstructed from scratch on every ajax request?

Thanks a lot.

Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [JSF lifecycle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSFIntro10.html), more specifically the **Restore View Phase** and **Render Response Phase** parts, you can find what are you looking for:

**Restore View Phase**

> If the request for the page is an initial request, the JavaServer Faces implementation creates an empty view during this phase and the life cycle advances to the render response phase. The empty view will be populated when the page is processed during a postback.
>
> If the request for the page is a postback, a view corresponding to this page already exists. During this phase, the JavaServer Faces implementation restores the view by using the state information saved on the client or the server.

**Render Response Phase**

> During this phase, the JavaServer Faces implementation delegates authority for rendering the page to the JSP container if the application is using JSP pages. If this is an initial request, the components represented on the page will be added to the component tree as the JSP container executes the page. If this is not an initial request, the components are already added to the tree so they needn't be added again. In either case, the components will render themselves as the JSP container traverses the tags in the page.

In short words, when you perform an Ajax request, you already have the view there. JSF will just search the components you want to rerender through it, just after their model have been updated, and update the view with their new values. In case of `c:forEach`, it's not a component, but a tag handler, so it's evaluated **before that**.

Related to the link you posted, have a look at this page about [the difference between components and tag handlers](https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat). They just have different lifecycles, so take care when mixing them.

Comment: Hi Biker, so we are saying that jstl tags are re-evaluated even during ajax calls? The examples on the web seem to say yes. The thing that is a little confusing for me is that if jstl tags are evaluated only when the view is built (that is different from restored from saved state, as the article says), one would think that they should not be considered during an ajax call.

Comment: Actually, they're considered. An ajax call is a postback call, which fires an standard JSF lifecycle. So, when reaching to Restore View Phase, JSF already has the view built, but has to restore the parts to be processed. If you specify a tag handler to be processed, JSF will reevaluate it and perform the changes in the view tree. In the example you posted both, `rich:tabPanel` and `c:forEach` work at this level, so it explains you why not to use `ui:repeat`, which is evaluated later and consecuently isn't able to create `rich:tab` components itself.